# Solr: indexing on the example films doesn't return any result

Tags: solr

I just started to learn Solr, when I create the index on the "films" example, I got only 5 documents in Solr Admin which is of course wrong. Here are the steps from [Steve Rowe](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/master/solr/example/films) that I followed:

```
bin/solr stop
rm server/logs/*.log
rm -Rf server/solr/films/
bin/solr start
bin/solr create -c films
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/films/schema -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
    "add-field" : {
        "name":"name",
        "type":"text_general",
        "multiValued":false,
        "stored":true
    },
    "add-field" : {
        "name":"initial_release_date",
        "type":"pdate",
        "stored":true
    }
}'
bin/post -c films example/films/films.json
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/films/config/params -H 'Content-type:application/json'  -d '{
"update" : {
  "facets": {
    "facet.field":"genre"
    }
  }
}'
```

I got nothing when I do my search: 
http://192.168.112.141:8983/solr/films/browse?q=batman

What am I missing here? I even tried to remove solr and reinstall it with no success.

From SolAdmin I can see 1100 docs are there in the core.

Thank you very much, any clue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing the query `q=batman` you mention no field to search against. Usual Solr syntax is `field:value`. In your case I assume it should be `q=name:batman`

As additional information - when no field is specified, Solr picks up the default field from the configuration, but most likely in your case, it was the field that is not existing in the index.

Comment: Thank you, specifying the name field get me result, however, in the author's original post there is no field needed

Comment: @Choix from the link you sent - 
Let's get searching!
     Search for 'Batman':
       http://localhost:8983/solr/films/query?q=name:batman
I see a name field there

Comment: Thank you. Scroll to the page bottom you will see no field is required

Comment: at the bottom of the page there is browse search handler, and you do not add it via {
"set" : {
  "browse": {
    "hl":"on",
    "hl.fl":"name"
    }
  }
} You could see, that hl.fl param is set to name, which is actually a field we used for search. hl stands for highlighting

Comment: What do you mean? I ran it too already and query without specifying field does not get result for me, can you initiate a chat room and let's go there?

Comment: oh, okay, i ll do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167870/discussion-between-mysterion-and-choix).

Comment: Thank you very much Mysterion for helping me on my first Solr question.